# How to extract a specific database column from the query result

Tags: c#, .net

I have this SQL query that successfully returns the desired result.

Basically for the given `NameId` there are multiple unique `PlaceId`.

SQL query:

```
Select 
    NameId, PlaceId 
From 
    db_schemaA_tableA a
Left Join 
    db_schemaB_tableB b On a.Id = b.NameId
Left Join 
    db_schemaC_tableC c On a.ItemId = c.ItemId
Where 
    a.Id = 'C330ads'
```

**NOTE**: `NameId` and `PlaceId` are of datatype GUID

SQL result:

```
NameId   | PlaceId
---------+---------- 
C330ads  | 705ddf
C330ads  | 618rre
```

In C# this is what I have

Entity class

```
public class Name 
{
      public Guid NameId {get; set:}
      public Guid PlaceId {get; set;}
}
```

Class with DB connection method

```
public List<Name> GetNames(Guid someId)
{
     SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
     var result = new List<Name>();

     string query = @"Select NameId, PlaceId from db_schemaA_tableA a
     left join db_schemaB_tableB b on a.Id = b.NameId
     left join db_schemaC_tableC c on a.ItemId = c.ItemId
     where a.Id= @NameId";

     //HOW CAN I GET ALL PlaceIds ?

     using(connection)
     {
         result = connection.Query<Name>(query, new {NameId = someId});
     }

     return result;
}
```

How can I get all the corresponding `PlaceId` for the given `NameId` in C#?

Thank you

Comment: `SqlConnection` doesn't define a method `.Query<T>(...)` Presumably whatever is wrong with this is in that method. Please can you show your code for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wasn't a Dapper issue, as I initially thought. It was something much simpler.

I had the columns NameId and PlaceId in sql as such:

```
    NameId   | PlaceId
    ------------------- 
    C330ads  | 705ddf
    C330ads  | 618rre
```

In C#, I had to provide  the variable/variables I needed to map values to

```
    public Guid Name {get; set;}
    public Guid Place{get; set;}
```

So in my query I had to select both variables:

```
     Select NameId as Name, PlaceId as Place from db_schemaA_tableA ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to use Dapper. you can do it in this way.

Add [Dapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper/) package if not already added.

```
using Dapper;

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    CommandDefinition command = new CommandDefinition(query, null, null, null, CommandType.Text);
    result = connection.Query<List<Name>>(command).ToList();
}
```